# forEach in scala shows expected: Consumer[_ >:Path] actual: (Path) => Boolean

Tags: scala, scala-streams

Wrong syntax problem in recursively deleting scala files

```
Files.walk(path, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .forEach(Files.deleteIfExists)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to pass a scala-style function to a method expecting a java-8-style function. There's a couple libraries out there that can do the conversion, or you could write it yourself (it's not complicated), or probably the simplest is to just convert the java collection to a scala collection that has a `foreach` method expecting a scala-style function as an argument:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

Files.walk(path, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .iterator().asScala
        .foreach(Files.deleteIfExists)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 2.12 I expect this should work:

```
...forEach(Files.deleteIfExists(_: Path))
```

The reason you need to specify argument type is because expected type is `Consumer[_ >: Path]`, not `Consumer[Path]` as it would be in Scala.

If it doesn't work (can't test at the moment), try

```
val deleteIfExists: Consumer[Path] = Files.deleteIfExists(_)

...forEach(deleteIfExists)
```

Before Scala 2.12, Joe K's answer is the correct one.